# Should I enable Cloud SQL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have began developping an appengine website, and realised that I was going to need to make lots of random queries on my database, an awkard thing to do with datastore or ndb. heres a sample code of my "random" queries:

```
q = UserList.query(ancestor = listakey)
if los.rand_num < self.rand_num:
    q2 = q.filter(UserList.rand_num > self.rand_num)

elif los.rand_num > self.rand_num:
    q2 = q.filter(UserList.rand_num > los.rand_num)

users = q2.fetch(1)
while len(users) == 0:
        users = q.fetch(1)
        self.rand_num = random.random()
        self.put()
```

where .rand_num are random floats asigned to a winner and a loser entity, in order to ensure this wont appear again in the next query. this random numbers are updated every some queries, and although the results are quite random, this appears to be wasting too many resources since the average latency is about 500ms. on the other hand, i am sure in a SQL database this would be much more efficient

my question is, does anybody has any suggestions on how to improve my code or should I get Cloud SQL?

Comment: Note that because Cloud SQL is basically a MySQL server, it doesn't scale nearly as well as the datastore. Imagine 1000 concurrent visitors, each served by a different app engine instance in different Google Datacenters; no way you can pool those 1000 connections to your Cloud SQL server, so you are at the limit of what one MySQL can handle. Now visitor number 1001 comes along, and the server is out of connections...

Comment: i thought cloud sql could manage multiple instances in order to scalate, just as datastore. you mean it is just like an external server with no scalation capabilities or that I should configure that myself?

Comment: Perhaps assign pre allocated int model id's, keep track of the highest allocated and then choose from those then get by id?

Comment: @TomasRaies: I may have over-simplified a little; you do get automatically replicated copies of the database, so each datacenter has it's own local MySQL server. But you can still run out of connections. :-)

Comment: oh sorry i didn't get that before. either way, you were right, using cloud sql would be over complicating this. i'll better just debugg my code until is fast enough